# Create a link to a part of a webpage in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

How would I go about creating a link to a specific part of a webpage in a vb.net program?

I want it to act like the links in the contents page on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET#Syntax).

The link will go here:

```
Private Sub LauncherHelp_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button <> MouseButtons.Right Then Return
    Dim cms = New ContextMenuStrip
    Dim item1 = cms.Items.Add("Copy Link")
    item1.Tag = 1
    AddHandler item1.Click, AddressOf menuChoice_LauncherHelp
    cms.Show(popuw_Link, e.Location)
End Sub

Private Sub menuChoice_LauncherHelp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim item = CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
    Dim selection = CInt(item.Tag)
    If selection = 1 Then
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText("link") '<== The link goes here.'
        MessageBox.Show("Link Copied to Clipboard.")
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm grateful for any help.

Regards

T54

P.S. Please feel free to correct my spelling.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to VB. It is achieved with HTML anchors.
These are placed at the particular position within the HTML markup an being referenced in the link via hash tag #

For example you put <a href="#chapter1"> in the source of i.e. index.html and open it in the browser via index.html#chapter1

The browser will then scroll to the position of the anchor tag.

Comment: So its not at all possible in any way?

Comment: You would have to know the anchor's name in order to directly link there.

Depends on what your application is doing in general. Without having the desired section's achor name you can just link to the page itself but not forcing the browser to scroll to a particular section.

Comment: I'm trying to link to this page: github.com/Tensounder54/SDLPoP/blob/master/doc/Readme.txt at lines 141 - 145

Comment: This page does not contain any HTML anchors because it is displaying a raw text file